# Is it possible to implement BLE-like proximity service with BL 3.0 on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

If I make one device (e.g. Android tablet) indefinitely discoverable and make a second one (e.g. phone with BL 3.0 support) search for devices, it seems like I'll be able to extract server device name (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). By device name, I can deduct where in the world is the second device. What is wrong with sucn an approach? (I'm completely new to Android, just validating feasibility of some idea).

The problem with BLE is - 70% of android devices still have OS version < 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it within limits - I have some software running on my Mac that automatically locks the screen when my Bluetooth phone goes out of range.  It doesn't use BLE.

One issue that you will have is the power consumption is greater than BLE, so battery life may be affected.

Another is that as the transmit power of the older Bluetooth can be higher than BLE you may find that the devices stay "in contact" for longer than you would like - It can certainly give you an idea of 'proximity/presence' although not really 'location'.

Also, if you pair the devices then they should be able to scan for one another without needing to be 'discoverable' - this is the approach used by the Mac software I mentioned.  I am not familiar enough with the Android BT APIs to know whether you can detect a paired device but then not connect.

Also, taking the device MAC from the advertisement rather than name is probably 'safer' - A user may rename their device, but they won't change the MAC.